# sass : The term 'sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: sass

I'm trying to get sass to run through the terminal and when I try, I get the error mentioned above. It seems that the installation of sass itself was successful because I can see it in my package.json file:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.51.0"
  }
```

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling sass, and restarting the client, but can't get the 'sass' keyword to work. I currently have my project located in a folder that github is also directed at so I can make pushing updates to github easier. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npx sass`, or create a new entry in the scripts section of your `{package,yarn}.json` file that calls `sass`.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "sass input.scss output.css",
}
```

Then, `npm run build` or `yarn build`, depending on which package manager you are using.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass

Comment: Using npx did the trick! I tried adding the build to my package.json file, but it spit out an error "ERROR: Task not found: "sass", input.scss", output.css"" Either way, it seems to be working with the npx command! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

npx helped me out as well. Thanks for that. Before I wrote:

```
sass --watch src/scss:public/css
```

and it turned out that it didnt find any sass but I fixed it with adding `npx` in front of sass.